# "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable" when using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I've download Selenium, and installed it in C: Programs and then open up the Jupyter notebook, so to complete the step, i did :

```
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "C:\Program Files\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.chrome(PATH)**
```

But I get this error:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow..  Please include your traceback error as text and format your code properly.   Also note that aside for your error, you should also change your path such that you have ```\\``` instead of ```\```.

Comment: You need to call `Chrome`, not `chrome`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
webdriver.chrome(PATH)
```

to

```
webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
```

In webdriver, `chrome` is a submodule whereas `Chrome` is a function.